# Two methods which can't run concurrently, how to write unit tests for this case, or make it testable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency, architecture

Let's say I have two methods in my class `MethodA` and `MethodB`. Those methods are run in async, and I don't want that they run at the same time. 
In the app, `MethodA` is called by the user, but `MethodB` is run by a Timer in a background thread.

How I see the implementation in C#ish pseudocode:

```
class MyClass 
{
     private static object _lock = new object();

     public async Task MethodA()
     {
          lock(_lock)
          {
              await DoSomeStuff();
          }
     }

     public async Task MethodB()
     {
          if(Monitor.IsEntered(_lock)
                return;
          lock(_lock)
          {
              await DoSomeStuff();
          }
     }
}
```

So first question is - is above approach correct? I guess that's more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

So the second questions is - assuming that the approach is correct, how I can unit test, that `MethodA` waits for `MethodB`, and that `MethodB` doesn't run when `MethodA` is running? Or how can I refactor it so that's testable?

EDIT: accordingly to comments, changed from using flags to a lock.

Comment: What is `WaitForBToFinish` ? Can you show that please, it seems to be a critical method. + How are you calling `MethodA` and `MethodB` ?

Comment: The problem with flags is if both the method enter at the same time, you could get past the check and have them running concurrently. Can't you just use a [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) instead?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use a lock?

Comment: There is no reason, my current concern is to make this testable, I changed the "implementation" to use a lock.

Comment: You can't use `await` in a `lock`

Comment: @user3185569: MethodA is called by the user, MethodB by a timer periodically in a background thread

Comment: @Nkosi yes, that's why I used flags in the first approach, forgot about the await :-) @user3185569 Wrote the correct approach with `SemaphoreSlim`, testability of the code is still my concern

Comment: As it is your code won't compile.

Comment: Sure, that's why I wrote that's pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean flags are the obsolete way to synchronize two threads. It causes race conditions when one thread can read a value of `false` while other thread is updating the value to `true`;

Since your case it not straightforward (B shouldn't way for B to end, while A should wait), then I would change the class use a `Semaphore` like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    public async Task MethodA()
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();

        await DoSomeStuff();

        semaphore.Release();
    }

    public async Task MethodB()
    {
        bool success = await semaphore.WaitAsync(1);

        if (!success)
            return;

        await DoSomeStuff();

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

I would consider putting all that in `try..catch..finally` block and release the semaphore in the finally block, but i'm trying to keep it simple while you can add that yourself.

### Unit testing:

This is not straight forward to test. Taking threads into account, you might need to repeat the test multiple times to reach a case of failure. You might need to introduce an overload for method A that waits for some times, which might prove that method B is waiting for it. Here is the test. To test the case of failure, change `new SemaphoreSlim(1);` to `new SemaphoreSlim(2);` and the test would fail because `MethodB` would start before `MethodA` ends.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestingMyClassThreadSync()
{
    int repeatTimes = 100;

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter++ <= repeatTimes)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        Task tA = myClass.MethodA();

        Task tB = myClass.MethodB();

        Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tA, tB);

        bool bFinishedBeforeA = finishedTask == tA;

        if (bFinishedBeforeA)
            Assert.Fail();
    }

}
```

I would introduce an overload:

```
public async Task MethodA(long waitMilliseconds = 0)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();

    await DoSomeStuff();
    await Task.Delay(waitMilliseconds);
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Then Call it from unit testing as `MethodA(5000);`

Comment: just wanted to edit it to something like you wrote after realizing that await is not allowed in a lock :)

Comment: but do you thing it's possible to somehow test this scenarios in unit tests?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk I'm editing the question now to post on how to test this.

Comment: interesting approach, I can additionally check for method calls inside the `DoSomeStuff` from which methods it came first. So thank you for pointing me in the direction :) However, assuming I run the `MethodA` for some time, and directly then `MethodB` as in the test, wouldn't `MethodB` finish before `MethodA` every time due `if(!success)` part? And that's the expected behavior but the test seem to fail because of that?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk you can return `Task<bool>` from MethodB in order to check if it really executed or just returned due to A being running. you can then `return success` from MethodB and check the condition to `if (bFinishedBeforeA) && finishedTask.Result)`

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Another approach would be to wait for method A to finish inside methodB, but not call `DoSomeStuff` and just end MethodB After that.

Comment: thanks for clarifications about how I can tackle this architectural concern. I think I know now how to approach it :)